# How to call .cs file from a .aspx.cs in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, controls

I have a `a1.aspx.cs` file and i have created new `class1.cs` file. I want to call a function in a1.aspx.cs which is in class1.cs

When i  write a method in `a1.aspx.cs` everything works fine, but when i try to copy paste the contents which are there in button click event into `class1.cs` file and call that function i **am unable to get all the controls that i have used in my web page,what parameters am i supposed to pass**??

and error comes as

```
Error   1   The name 'DropDownList1' does not exist in the current context
```

and many more such errors.
Please help me to understand how to call a function in `a1.aspx.cs`

Comment: Can I ask why would you pass the controls, rather than just values? As Astander mentioned "Typically I prefer to keep UI logic with the UI itself, purely for simplicity reasons." -> you should follow this advice, it will ease testing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass the controls the the class method as parametes

Something like

```
public class YourClass
{
    public void YourMethod (DropDownList dowpdownlist)
    {
        //do stuff here with dowpdownlist
    }
}
```

This does not seem like the best way to handle things.

*Typically I prefer to keep UI logic with the UI itself, purely for simplicity reasons.*

Comment: +1 for `Typically I prefer to keep UI logic with the UI itself, purely for simplicity reasons.`

Comment: +1 from my side too for `Typically I prefer to keep UI logic with the UI itself, purely for simplicity reasons.`

Comment: and what if i have many other controls like textbox,HtmlEditor(ajax control) etc... i need to pass everything?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you will have to do that. That is why we are trying to get you to keep it closer to the UI. Unless you wish to reuse this method with other forms, move it back to the UI.

Comment: Or, you can use the concept of partial classes to have the same class split into two physical files and still get them compiled as one.

Answer (score 1):

of course, you will never get any UI controls from aspx file in the `class file (i.e. .cs file)`. you'll either have to pass the UI controls in the paramters of methods.

Or

it will be better if you just pass the value of dropdown to your method in the class file.

**.cs class file**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void SaveData(string selectedValue)
    {
        // do some work with the value
    }
}
```

**.aspx.cs file**

```
public partial class AttendLiveSession : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void imgbtnGetItButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.SaveData(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not be using the UI controls in your class1.cs file. But if required, you can pass the control "DropDownList1" to the function in class1.cs and then refer the control in the method.

**EDIT:**
I would also like to add that, if you plan to write only UI related code in class1.cs file then you can always change the class declaration in class1.cs as below:

```
public partial class a1
{

}
```

Now you will be able to access all your controls and events in this class.
This will just be the same class, but in two different physical files.